# What precautions should be taken while developing first version of AppExchange App?

Tags: appexchange, isv, app, app-development

To avoid any problems that might occur while updating app to next version.

As second version may have new fields/objects/pages/classes/static resources/settings etc or update/delete above mentioned older resources. Updating/Deleting those resources in next version shouldn't be a problem because of wrong decisions taken during development of first version.

Answer (score 1):

You should plan your first release carfully. New fields are usually no problem. But after you upload your package as release, most components can't be deleted or renamed anymore. So refactoring is limited.

The reason for that is, that the concept of the platform is to allow users who have installed you app to customize or build (e. g. integrations) on the top of your app. Changes and deletions would break that.

Therefore I would recommend to start with beta packages where you keep more options to make changes.

Comment: Using beta packages is definitely the way to go.  The project I'm working on spent about 3 months publishing beta releases to our beta testers before ever cutting the first production release version.  While still in beta, you can do almost anything to the package.